# What's up with stdout in Gambit-C Scheme?

Tags: scheme

What's up with this, how do I capture the output from my Gambit-C program?

```
$ gsi -e "(pp 'hello?)"
hello?

$ gsi -e "(pp 'hello?)" >asdf
hello?

$ gsi -e "(pp 'hello?)" 2>asdf
hello?

$ cat asdf
```

It should have put the output of the program into `asdf`, but it's empty!
Is there a compile-time or run-time option I can set to make it treat stdout like a normal unix program? (Preferably compile-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with `pp`, but you seem to want `pretty-print`:

```
$ gsi -e "(pretty-print 'hello?)" > test
$ cat test
hello?
$
```

Comment: You're right.  I saw `pp` being used in lots of Gambit-C examples, but it's got specific semantics for the REPL, whereas `pretty-print` redirects as expected.  I thought `pp` was just a synonym for `pretty-print`.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea, pp is a totally different function (although confusingly, it is the _same_ in Chicken :S), and it allows really neat things like seeing the expansion of macros. Check out some macros sometime -- it's really useful and interesting.